# Drag and Drop does not work on mobile device - ng2-dnd Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, drag-and-drop

I am making use of the ng2-dnd library - https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd. I am able to successfully drag and drop items from place to place. However, when it comes to dragging and dropping on mobile devices it does not work. When trying to drag and drop the device thinks the user wants to scroll the screen up or down and not click and drop. I'd also like to note I'm using Ionic 3 - not that it matters. Is there a workaround here? Not sure if posting my code is useful, as it is basically the same as the sortable data in the examples from the resource I linked to. Thanks

Comment: I don't think drag & drop feature is meant for mobile devices.

Comment: I know it is maybe not the answer you need but I would implement the drag and drop without this library as it may not handle touch based events.

Comment: Would there be a way to override it and add touch based events?